# Prove that $G$ is Eulerian if and only if every block of $G$ is Eulerian.

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Prove that $G$ is Eulerian if and only if every block of $G$ is Eulerian.

**Attempt:**

If G is Eulerian, then G has a partition into cycles  edge-disjoint. I don't know how to apply it, though.

If every block is Eulerian, then every vertex in $G$ which is the edge-disjoint union of its blocks has even degree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you said by Veblen's theorem the edges can be partitioned into edge-disjoint edges.

Assume a block induces a graph with a vertex $v$ of odd degree, it follows that there must be one cycle for which $v$ contains only one of the two edges adjacent to it. If we add all of the vertices in that cycle the graph will still be $2$-connected ( proving this is slightly tricky, we have to consider the case in which we remove $v$ but it's doable). This contradicts the maximality of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Statement: if every block of $G$ is eulerian then $G$ is eulerian

Proof: If every block is eulerian then degree of each vertex of the block should be even (even the separating vertex). For any separating vertex in $G$, say $u$, its degree in all the blocks that contain *u* is even. Hence the degree of $u$ in $G$ is also even. Hence $G$ is eulerian.

Statement: if $G$ is eulerian then every block of $G$ is eulerian

Proof: Let us assume that there exist blocks with odd degree vertices.
Let us create a graph $H$ with these blocks and the separating vectices as new vertices of $H$. Let us colour all the vertices which represent block as red and other as blue. There can  be an edge only between vertices of different colour and only between the separating vertex (blue) and the the block (red vertex) which contains it.

Claim:: graph $H$ should be acyclic. This is because otherwise if we consider the blocks and the common separating vertices which forms the cycle in $H$, then we get a cycle in $G$. (a block is 2-connected).

But our graph will have a cycle, because, each block must have even number of odd degree vertices, hence the degree of the block in $H$ has to be greater than 2.
Hence our assumption is wrong, there is no block with odd degree vertices.
Hence all blocks are eulerian.